# look like css wont reload but not all the times

Tags: html, css, django

when I visit the page most of the times it is ok .
but some times when I keep pressing refresh or  for example if I am in a another page and then came back to that page via a link , page wont be shown right ,look likes it could not load the CSS file .
I delete the CSS and then I reload the page and I saw page is just like those times that I mention above , so I am pretty sure it is about page's CSS .
Next when page is disorder I click on refresh and page gets right
another thing I should add is ,always I have this problem with large screens browsers like in laptop or pc but never experience this problem with tablet or phone and small devices
I design that web site with Nice page so every page has 2 CSS (nicepage.css and page.css)files ,and 2
JS files
you can visit the page here :
https://www.drhosseinchi.ir/docs/first/
so what can I do ?

Comment: You can use force refresh ctrl + f5 (Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are a beginner to web development. You need to read more about "cache". Browsers usually cache files such as css to save user's data. Try renaming your css file or make it internal by moving it to page header section and everything should work.